# Does Hinek and Lam's Paper prove that Common Modulus Attacks is possible with non-coprime public exponents?

Tags: rsa, attack

We know that Common Modulus Attacks work with coprime public exponents $(e',s)$ such that $${e_1}s+{e_2}t=\gcd(e_1,e_2)=1$$

I am reading Hinek and Lam's Paper: [Common Modulus Attacks on Small Private Exponent RSA and Some Fast Variants (in Practice)](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/037.pdf). Got confused, it seems they proved that Common Modulus Attacks would work with non-coprime public exponents, with the condition of "Small Private Exponent RSA".

Is my understanding correct? Is there some example for this?

Comment: BTW this is related to an ongoing CTF https://ctf.dicega.ng/

Comment: Mmm..., good to know this is related to CTF challenge happening now. I did not know that, I was just writing some blog for my RSA attack survey and got puzzle on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first common modulus attack is described by G. J. Simmons

- 1983 [A ‘weak’ privacy protocol using the RSA crypto algorithm](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0161-118391857900)

and if there is a **common modulus** and the public exponents are **relatively prime** (i.e. $\gcd(e_1,e_2)=1$) then recovering the message is easy ( no factoring).

As pointed in section 5 of your linked article;

> Howgrave-Graham and Seifert’s small private exponent attack on common modulus RSA [[1]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-46701-7_14) improves upon Guo’s attack in several ways. In particular, the attack can be mounted with only two instances of RSA (although it gets stronger with more), **the problems associated with relatively prime quantities are not a concern** and, most importantly, the attack (even with only two instances) is much stronger.

So your understanding is correct.

Comment: Thanks @kelalaka, wonder if there is any Sage Python coding example for this.

Comment: @ZixiSean the best way is asking to the authors, They may have some implementation, however, these are generally theoretic works so that you may not found one.